# Dynamically changing HTML form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I need to change the elements in a form based on a choice (radio button perhaps).
So that 2 forms are potentially available on a page.

So far I've come up with this but it doesn't seem to work...

```
//javascript

function FormChange(toChange){
    if (toChange){
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById('li1').innerHTML;
        var newHTML = "Company Name: " + "<input type="text" name="companyname" />";
        document.getElementById('li1').innerHTML = newHTML;
}

//HTML

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<li id="li1">Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
</form>

<input type = "button" value="Change that bad boy" onclick="FormChange(true)"/>
```

My Intention was to remove the firstname field and replace it with the companyname field.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You don't close the li tag... that could be an issue.

Comment: If you combine the two answers thus far you will probably get working code.  It is important when you have an issue with javascript to check and see if there are any errors on the console.  This definitely would have thrown a few.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the two current answers together, and adding a little error handling:

```
function FormChange(toChange) {
    if (toChange) {
        var elt = document.getElementById('li1');
        if (elt) {
            var newHTML = "Company Name: " + "<input type='text' name='companyname' />";
            elt.innerHTML = newHTML;
        }
    }
}


<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<ul>
<li id="li1">Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function FormChange(toChange){
    if (toChange){
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById('li1').innerHTML;
        var newHTML = "Company Name: " + "<input type='text' name='companyname' />";
        document.getElementById('li1').innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNtc2/)

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the inner double quotes in your innerHTML text.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `{`!

Fix:

```
function FormChange(toChange) {
    if (toChange) {
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById('li1').innerHTML;
        var newHTML = "Company Name: " + "<input type="text" name="companyname" />";
        document.getElementById('li1').innerHTML = newHTML;
    } // <-- this was missing!
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, in my code it exists but i didn't copy the else part so i missed it out, opps

Answer (score 0):

why don't use jquery???, do something like this:

```
$("#li1").change(function(){
alert("it changed");//here do whatever you want to
});
```

I think it's easier and it's more read readable.(don't forget to import the Jquery library)

Comment: jQuery is certainly the modern, advanced way to go, but it's clear that the questioner is still learning the basics of JavaScript and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tweaks to make changes ONLY when the text is `"Firstname:"` so repeated calls don't mess with the DOM unnecessarily (see the performance point 9 [here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas))

JS:

```
function FormChange() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('li1');
    var oldHTML = obj.innerHTML.substring(0,10);

    if (oldHTML=="Firstname:") {
        var newHTML = "Company Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"companyname\" />";
        obj.innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li id="li1">Firstname: <input name="firstname" type="text" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="FormChange();" value="Change that bad boy" />
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UMGPE/1/)**

**Further Notes:**

- `<li>` [should be contained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/li) in either: `<ol>`, `<ul>` or `<menu>`
- you need to [escape quotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Escaping_characters) in variables properly